# React router how to get current path and look for its updates

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hello I have question how can I get current path of app with search params and look for its updates. For example I have `localhost3000/?filter=breakfastdinner` and I want to go back to `localhost3000/?filter=breakfast`. I want to wait for URL updates to use useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i <= recipeTypesArray.length - 1; i++) {
      if (searchParams.get("filter")?.includes(recipeTypesArray[i])) {
        dispatch(
          recipeAction.addFilters({
            content: recipeTypesArray[i],
            filterName: "filterTypes",
          })
        );
      }
      if (!searchParams.get("filter")?.includes(recipeTypesArray[i])) {
        dispatch(
          recipeAction.removeFilters({
            content: recipeTypesArray[i],
            filterName: "filterTypes",
          })
        );
      }
    }
    initial = false;
    console.log(chosenFiltersTypes);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `useRouter();` and pass the route in the useEffect deps, something like:

```
const { asPath } = useRouter(); // asPath or whatever from the router

useEffect(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i <= recipeTypesArray.length - 1; i++) {
      if (searchParams.get("filter")?.includes(recipeTypesArray[i])) {
        dispatch(
          recipeAction.addFilters({
            content: recipeTypesArray[i],
            filterName: "filterTypes",
          })
        );
      }
      if (!searchParams.get("filter")?.includes(recipeTypesArray[i])) {
        dispatch(
          recipeAction.removeFilters({
            content: recipeTypesArray[i],
            filterName: "filterTypes",
          })
        );
      }
    }
    initial = false;
    console.log(chosenFiltersTypes);
  }, [asPath]);
```

**Edit:**

For react-router how about these hooks (based on your goal)?

```
useHistory
useLocation
useParams
useRouteMatch
```

I think all of them are supported in v6 too.

https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks

Comment: Hello sir, useRouter() is from next.js I am asking about react-router v6

Comment: @Kay I added some more details above that might be helpful.

Comment: I have got it!. useLocation.search was the thing! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `useLocation()` hook.

```
 const { hash, pathname, search } = useLocation();
```